# Internal microphone doesn't work but headphone microphone does

Tags: 16.04, drivers, microphone

I'm currently on Ubuntu 16.04 with a Lenovo Thinkpad E490S.

Without earbuds plugged in, pauvcontrol shows 2 ports, "Internal Microphone (unplugged)" and "Microphone (plugged in)". Neither of the two work. I've already tried unlocking channels and setting one to the lowest.

With earbuds plugged in, pauvcontrol shows the same two ports, but "Microphone (plugged in)" works normally.

How do I get the mic working without earbuds?